# Why componentWillReceiveProps is not called?

Tags: reactjs

At child, I need to listen for state changed at parent, I tried to do so as:

**Child**

```
class deleteDriverAlert extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          show: false
        };
      }

      componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        console.log("componentWillReceiveProps . . . . .");
        this.setState({ show: nextProps.dataset.showDeleteAll });  
      }

    render() {

        return (
            <SweetAlert
            warning
            showCancel
            confirmBtnText="Yes, delete it!"
            confirmBtnBsStyle="danger"
            cancelBtnBsStyle="default"
            title="Are you sure?"

            onConfirm={this.props.dataset.onConfirm}
            onCancel={this.props.dataset.onCancel}
            show={this.state.show}
            >
            You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!
            </SweetAlert>
        );
    }
}

export default deleteDriverAlert;
```

then, in the parent, I add the child as:

```
<deleteDriverAlert data-showDeleteAll={this.state.show_delete_all} data-onConfirm={this.deleteDriver} data-onCancel={this.onCancelDelete} />
```

now, although I do change the property state `show_delete_all` at parent, `componentWillReceiveProps` is not called at child.

Any idea?

Comment: Try not to using `dataset` but just naming your props `showDeleteAll`, `onConfirm` and `onCancel`

Comment: the same, it did not work for the boolean show, however, calling methods worked

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps` is not called because its properties are not changing... Ma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things, firstly you don't need to set the props into the state of the child component to be able to use them dynamically. The problem is most likely with the way you are changing the state in the parent.

Here is a simple example of the same thing you are trying to do:

The Parent component has its own state and a method to change it which is bound to the parent context and is flipped with a button. Then the state is passed to the child as a prop:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Child from './Child';

class Parent extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { show: false };
    this.flipShow = this.flipShow.bind(this);
  }

  flipShow(){
    this.setState({show: !this.state.show})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Parent</p>
        <button onClick={this.flipShow}>Show</button>
        <Child show={this.state.show} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Parent;
```

Then the child simply passes the prop through. Note: in the example below the componentWillReceiveProps is unnecessary but I only put it there to show that it does fire with this set up.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SweetAlert from './SweetAlert';

class Child extends Component {
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    console.log("receiving new props");
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <SweetAlert
        show={this.props.show}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default Child;
```

TL;DR
If componentWillReceiveProps isn't firing, it's a problem with the Parent component and the way it is setting the prop value not the child.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but I don't think react will re-render the child component when the parent component change state, which makes sense because the state is a local thing specific to that component. But since you're not using a state management library it would make more sense to use the new React Context API in this scenario, to pass changing data down to the Child component, and it looks pretty straightforward

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to upgrade my reactjs to latest version but I have issues https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49922928/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-bool-of-undefined-after-upgrade-react/49923003?noredirect=1#comment86862038_49923003