# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bool' of undefined after upgrade reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have just upgraded my reactjs project from `15.4.2` to `16.3.2` , the project compiles fine however, in the browser, I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bool' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (propTypes.js:3)
    at __webpack_require__ (propTypes.js:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (propTypes.js:3)
    at __webpack_require__ (propTypes.js:3)
    at Object.exports.__esModule (propTypes.js:3)
    at __webpack_require__ (propTypes.js:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (propTypes.js:3)
    at __webpack_require__ (propTypes.js:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (propTypes.js:3)
    at __webpack_require__ (propTypes.js:3)
```

but I could know where is the line causing the error.. maybe I have to upgrade other packages too?

here is what I have currently:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.17",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "create-react-class": "^15.6.3",
    "cross-env": "^5.1",
    "laravel-mix": "^1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "react": "16.3.2",
    "react-dom": "16.3.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ajv": "^6.4.0",
    "animate.css": "^3.1.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "dom-tools": "^0.1.4",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "history": "^4.7.2",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "jquery-slimscroll": "^1.3.6",
    "metismenu": "^2.5.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.28.3",
    "react-bootstrap-sweetalert": "^4.3.1",
    "react-infinite-grid": "^0.4.0",
    "react-infinite-scroller": "^1.1.4",
    "react-metismenu": "^1.4.0-alpha.2",
    "react-pace": "^1.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-table": "^6.8.0",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-persist": "^4.9.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "ree-validate": "^1.0.15",
    "rndoam": "^0.1.0",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.76.0"
  }
```

**EDIT**

Full error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bool' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (propTypes.js:3)
    at __webpack_require__ (propTypes.js:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (propTypes.js:3)
    at __webpack_require__ (propTypes.js:3)
    at Object.exports.__esModule (propTypes.js:3)
    at __webpack_require__ (propTypes.js:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (propTypes.js:3)
    at __webpack_require__ (propTypes.js:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (propTypes.js:3)
    at __webpack_require__ (propTypes.js:3)
(anonymous) @ propTypes.js:3
__webpack_require__ @ propTypes.js:3
(anonymous) @ propTypes.js:3
__webpack_require__ @ propTypes.js:3
exports.__esModule @ propTypes.js:3
__webpack_require__ @ propTypes.js:3
(anonymous) @ propTypes.js:3
__webpack_require__ @ propTypes.js:3
(anonymous) @ propTypes.js:3
__webpack_require__ @ propTypes.js:3
(anonymous) @ propTypes.js:3
__webpack_require__ @ propTypes.js:3
(anonymous) @ propTypes.js:3
__webpack_require__ @ propTypes.js:3
(anonymous) @ propTypes.js:3
__webpack_require__ @ propTypes.js:3
Object.defineProperty.value @ propTypes.js:3
__webpack_require__ @ propTypes.js:3
(anonymous) @ propTypes.js:63
(anonymous) @ propTypes.js:66
```

Comment: Well, it is clearly coming from "prop-types" library. Maybe you need to update it too.

Comment: Can you post the code snippet where you use the prop-types

Comment: Also if the project is not that big, can you remove all instances of PropType validations, to be sure that is indeed the culprit?

Comment: Yes, its not that big, I've  removed its usage from everywhere, still get the same error..

Comment: Seems like you are not generating source maps in your webpack config. You should do that to get a better location of the error. Also you also need to take care of the compatibility between these packages `react, redux, react-redux, react-router, react-router-dom`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> but I could know where is the line causing the error.

You need to use the tools provided by your browser to see where the error happens. Otherwise it's easy to spend hours on simple errors.

Specifically, if you use Chrome, open the DevTools on the Sources tab. Click the pause button (blue on the image) to "Pause on Exceptions":

[image: pause on exceptions button]

Now if you reload the page with Sources pane open, you will see where exactly the code is breaking. It might be in a third party dependency that needs updating.

Finally, your sourcemap setup looks broken. It's odd that almost every call frame has the same line number. If you're not sure how to configure webpack correctly for development, I suggest using an officially supported tool like [Create React App](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) that configures it for you.

Answer (score 8):

https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

From the link above

`React.PropTypes has moved into a different package since React v15.5. Please use the prop-types library instead.`

You have to `import PropTypes from 'prop-types';` instead of relying on `React.PropTypes`

Comment: I've searched into the project, did not find `React.PropTypes` but only `import PropTypes from 'prop-types'`

Comment: something wrong should have happened with prop-types package, can you `npm uninstall prop-types` and then `npm install prop-types --save`

Comment: I tried but I got the same result, how can I know the line number that causes the error?

Comment: Can you post the full error stack. I feel like this is the error when webpack attempted to transpile and bundle the project, as error is coming from propTypes.js and not bundle.js.

Comment: "did not find React.PropTypes" — it's probably not in your code but in one of the dependencies.